# An integration involving Sinc function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, fourier-transform, approximate-integration

Sir,
I have been trying to find out the time average of the Intensity distribution of a scattering problem but I could not find the desired closed form answer of the following integral, which shows the averaging:

$$I_{avg}=\frac{A^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{sinc}^2{(\alpha \sin{\phi})} \operatorname{sinc}^2{(\alpha \cos{\phi})}\,d\phi$$

Where, $A$ is the amplitude and taken as a constant, $\alpha$ is also a constant and $\alpha>0$.

Sir,
would you kindly suggest me any method or any relevant reference from where I can get some help.

Comment: Even for $\alpha=1$, I am skeptical concerning a closed form.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici  ,Sir, is it possible to evaluate the closed form result of the integral if the limit goes from 0 to infinity instead of one complete period

Comment: It cannot converge

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici ,Yes Sir, it will not converge then. It was my mistake.

Comment: Beside numerical integration, I only think about approximations. You only need to consider the integral from $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$ I think.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici ,Sir, okay , if we consider only the 1/4 th of the period, in that case, what will be the out come.I am interested in the approximation technique also, as  you suggested.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici ,Sir, the plot in mathematica shows that I can take the limit from 0 to $\pi/2$.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici  Sir, Sorry for delayed reply. I think this approximation leads to answer closer to the actual closed form answer, we are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Possible ideas (?) in terms of approximation.*

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \text{sinc}(\alpha  \sin (\phi ))^2 \text{sinc}(\alpha  \cos (\phi ))^2\,d\phi=8\int_0^{\frac \pi4} \text{sinc}(\alpha  \sin (\phi ))^2 \text{sinc}(\alpha  \cos (\phi ))^2\,d\phi$$

Now, using series around $\phi=0$
$$ \text{sinc}(\alpha  \sin (\phi ))^2 \text{sinc}(\alpha  \cos (\phi ))^2=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n \phi^{2n}+O(\phi^{2p+2})$$ would make
$$I \sim 8 \sum_{n=0}^p a_n \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1}+O(\phi^{2p+3})$$

Using only
$$a_0=\frac{\sin ^2(\alpha )}{\alpha ^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad 
a_1=-\frac{\sin (\alpha ) \left(\left(\alpha ^2-3\right) \sin (\alpha )+3 \alpha  \cos
   (\alpha )\right)}{3 \alpha ^2}$$ for a few values of $\alpha$ some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.5 & 5.77842 & 5.77776 \\
 1.0 & 4.47144 & 4.46264 \\
 1.5 & 2.86061 & 2.82881 \\
 2.0 & 1.45419 & 1.39610 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Adding the next term, the results would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.5 & 5.77759 & 5.77776 \\
 1.0 & 4.46040 & 4.46264 \\
 1.5 & 2.82134 & 2.82881 \\
 2.0 & 1.38668 & 1.39610
\end{array}
\right)$$

Since you use Mathematica, generate as many coefficients as you wish for better and better results.

**Edit**

Still in terms of *approximations*, it seems that we could very accurately "fit" the integrand using
$$f(\phi)= \text{sinc}(\alpha  \sin (\phi ))^2 \text{sinc}(\alpha  \cos (\phi ))^2=b_0+b_1 \phi^2+b_2 \phi^4+b_3 \phi^6+b_4 \phi^8$$ the coefficients $b_i$ being exactly computed in order to match the values of
$$f(0) \qquad f\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\qquad f'\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=0\qquad f''(0)\qquad f''\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$ The formulae are not very complex (notice that the first and fourth conditions immediately give $b_0$ and $b_1$).

For example, for $\alpha=2$, the maximum error is $3.63 \times 10^{-5}$ and the integral of the approximation is $1.39600$ while numerical integration gives                                $1.39610$